# Symfony QueryParam with empty value

Tags: symfony, controller, query-string

I'm trying to use QueryParam on my symfony controller.

The problem that i dont want to accept the empty params in the query. But when i define the QueryParam with

```
@REST\QueryParam(name="test" , description="The test", requirements="\w+", strict=true, nullable=false)
```

and i try to call the web-service with `mysite.com/test=` it's still working.

What i have to do to refuse empty param in the request without testing in the code if the param is empty or not

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing weirdly enough the validation did not seem to work with the configuration `param_fetcher_listener` simply on `true`, but when I used `force`, everything suddenly worked:

```
# config.yml
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: force
```

And in the controller:

```
/**
 * @QueryParam(name="test" , description="The test", requirements="[a-zA-Z]+", strict=true, nullable=false, allowBlank=false)
 */
public function indexAction($test)
{
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return new JsonResponse($test);
}
```

Note that in my example there's multiple validations and only `?test=a` will work. No `test`, `?test=` and `?test=1` will all not work for specified reasons.

If anyone knows how to get it to work with `param_fetcher_listener: true` I'm curious :)

Also see the documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/param_fetcher_listener.html) for the implications of using `force`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
The problem that when i try to add the 'allowBlank=false' , i have an error, i'm working with symfony 2.8

Comment: Finally it's working, i update the /rest-bundle to 1.5 :) everything is working know :)